# Library modularization for Gradle, Android Studio, IDEA, and Git

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm developing an application with an Android client and a Java server.  Because there are shared libraries between the Android Studio client and the IDEA Server (and potentially other clients down the road), they need good modularization.

I've seen a very small amount of discussion here on how to implement several ways to address the modularization of  in-development libraries between Studio and IDEA, but never any discussion of how the mechanisms differ from each other.

How should I modularize my libraries for simplest management in the long run?  I'm leaning towards #3, are there subtleties that are going to bite me in the ass later on?

**Modularization mechanisms:**

Here are the options that I see, but I'm happy to accept others if they make more sense.

1. **Library code in IDEA modules** in the server project.  Have a facet that creates a jar for each module. Let the Android client depend on those jars.

   - *Advantage:* simplicity, maybe.
   - *Disadvantage:* cannot debug into libraries on Android (???).
2. Create a **git submodule** for each library, and include it in both projects.

   - *Pro:* library code is local to each project
   - *Con:* Two live copies of library code.
   - *Con:* Git complexity invariably [causes me a lot of pain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UllNDRXR1vM).
3. Server is an IDEA/Gradle project.  **Libraries are Gradle subprojects.**  Android client uses external gradle dependencies to libraries.

   - *Pro:* library code appears local to each project
   - *Con:* Cannot build client without having server source tree (could extract libraries into submodules later)
   - *Con:* Requires direct modification of settings.gradle and build.gradle.  Am I setting myself up for pain by modifying Gradle scripts outside of the gui?
   - *Con:* Not suited to re-use of libraries in other projects.
   - *Con:* After using it for a couple of months, I only know enough Gradle to know it's scary.
4. Entirely **separate projects** for each library, referenced as external dependencies.

   - *Pro:* All above pros.
   - *Con:* Dependency interactions?  CommLib depends on Model.  Server depends on both.  Will this cause me grief?
   - *Con:* Distributing source from several git modules will be annoying, especially if there are version dependencies.